# WKInterfacePicker: handle a tap event

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

Trying to simplify the UX in a Watch application by getting rid of a redundant button which a user has to tap in order to choose a selected item in `WKInterfacePicker` and perform a next step. Just want to replace the tap on this button with the tap on a picker.

Cannot find such API in [the class specification](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfacePicker_class/index.html) and the following quote haunts me:

> The user interacts with a picker by tapping it, using the crown to scroll through items, and tapping again to select an item.

Everything points to the fact that an item can be selected by tapping on a picker and we can get an access to that action programatically. Has anyone faced this task?

Answer (score 1):

To handle focus to picker did tap event use - pickerDidFocus.
If you want handle each tap now there are only one custom way. You need every time did focus picker programmaticaly call     [picker resignFocus]
Put picker into group and set background border image to it if you want to customize focus. Set picker focus style to none.

Comment: Ivan, thanks. I get your solution but it looks more than hacky :) Moreover emulating a focused state we can't get updates from the Digital Crown and it's a crucial point.

Answer (score -1):

just add a picker to your WKInterfaceController and create an IBAction to react on the pitch events:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the only available event to react is a pitch of the Digital Crown as you said. I want to handle tap events on the already focused picker. This way after users selecting the wanted item they could move to the next step by tapping on a picker instead of tapping on some button.

Comment: @DmitryGutsulyak Ok. If you need the tap, I have no idea. Sorry. Hopefully Apple will provide this with the next WatchOS version. It definitively makes sense.

Comment: Yep, considering the fact that this capability has already mentioned in the above quote `and tapping again to select an item`.

Comment: Three years later and I still don't think it's possible. I have tried adding a tap Gesture Recognizer to the picker and also to the Group containing the picker, but it doesn't fire.
It just seems like such an intuitive gesture!